# SyntaxError: Unterminated parenthetical, how to handle "( )"

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I am trying to clean up a string (anything that contains unwanted characters, diacritics, etc.) entered by a user and replace with just one string with no spaces.

I came across this error:

> Execution failed: SyntaxError: Unterminated parenthetical.

It stopped at this line: `idoff = accented.search(a2.charAt(i));`

I was able to update our old legacy code when we encountered several accented letters (diacritics). I saw a code that I could use to resolve it but somehow I cannot figure out to how fix this one.

```
function clean(a2) {


/* if string contains accented letters, index below and use regular text */

var accented = 'ÁÀÂÃÄÄÅÆáàâãäåąÇçćčÐÉÉÊËèéêëðęÍÍÎÏíîïłÑñńÖÓŐÓÔÕØöóőôõøÜŰÙÚÛÜüűúûŠšŸÿýŽžŻżŁ';
var regularText = 'AAAAAAAAaaaaaaaaCcccDEEEEeeeeeeIIIIiiilNnnOOOOOOOooooooUUUUUUuuuuSSYyyZzZzL';
var idoff = -1,new_text = '';
var lentext = a2.toString().length -1

for (i = 0; i <= lentext; i++) {
    idoff = accented.search(a2.charAt(i));
    if (idoff == -1) {
        new_text = new_text + a2.charAt(i);
    } else {
       new_text = new_text + regularText.charAt(idoff);
    }
}
// return new_text; 

/* Locate where in the string that contains ":", remove it including spaces and change string to lowercase */

var space = new_text.indexOf(":");
    if (space > -1) {
        var answer = new_text.substring(space);
        answer = answer.replace(/[\.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()"'+@<>?]/g,"")
        answer = answer.replace(/ /g,"");
        answer = answer.toLowerCase();
     } else {
        var answer = new_text;
        answer = answer.replace(/[\.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()"'+@<>?]/g,"")
        answer = answer.replace(/ /g,"");
        answer = answer.toLowerCase();
     }
     return answer;
 }
```

If string is like this `ABC-XYZ-LMN (AB12): XxxX Set Çompanÿ` I want to clean it up to this `xxxxsetcompany`.

Comment: The line `var lentext = a2.toString().length -1` does not end with a semi-colon. Is that a cut-and-paste error, or could it be the problem?

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I ran it again and still the same error and stopped at this code: idoff = accented.search(a2.charAt(i));

Comment: Can't reproduce, the code you posted is syntactically valid.

Comment: The problem isn't the syntax, it's a runtime error thrown because of an invalid regex.

Comment: Any strings before colon is eliminated. So I  updated the code above and somehow it works now.

Comment: @JMR you have an extra 'a' character in your regularText string.

Comment: `if (!!s.indexOf(a2.charAt(i))) { /* s contains a2.charAt(i) */ }`

Answer (score 3):

[`String.prototype.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) expects a regular expression, but you're passing in a character (string).  As you iterate over `a2` you eventually come across an open parenthesis (the one surrounding "AB12").  An open parenthesis is not a valid regex.

To fix this you could use [`String.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) instead.

However, I think a more elegant solution to your issue may look something like this:

```js
function clean(a2) {
  /* if string contains accented letters, index below and use regular text */
  const accented = 'ÁÀÂÃÄÄÅÆáàâãäåąÇçćčÐÉÉÊËèéêëðęÍÍÎÏíîïłÑñńÖÓŐÓÔÕØöóőôõøÜŰÙÚÛÜüűúûŠšŸÿýŽžŻżŁ';
  const regularText = 'AAAAAAAAaaaaaaaCcccDEEEEeeeeeeIIIIiiilNnnOOOOOOOooooooUUUUUUuuuuSSYyyZzZzL'.split('');

  let answer = '';

  a2.split('').forEach((char) => {
    let accentIndex = accented.indexOf(char);

    if (accentIndex > -1) {
      answer += regularText[accentIndex];
    } else {
      answer += char;
    }
  });

  answer = answer.replace(/\W/gi, '');

  return answer.toLowerCase();
}

console.log(clean('ABC-XYZ-LMN (AB12): XxxX Set Çompanÿ'));
```

Comment: Note that apps script is currently ES5. So, no arrow functions and `let`.(includes isn't available either)

Comment: Yep, I just find writing es6+ more enjoyable (and it's what I use normally), so I leave it up to the OP to transpile it to <=es5 if he wants to use it.  He could easily use something like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/en/repl) to get the proper version.

Answer (score 0):

Add the code after function clean(a2) {

```
var name = name;
name = name.replace(/[\])}[{(]/g, '');  
name = name.toLowerCase();
```

...

Comment: This doesn't cover all possible issues you may run into.  I usually like to avoid doing something like this for that reason.

Comment: I am fairly new to coding. I do appreciate your input and will keep it as a reference for later use. I will do more testing and hopefully I can utilize it. Thank you!

Comment: As noted by @TheMaster the snippet I have is using features of JS that are not supported in your environment.  You'll need to transpile them for the snippet to work (you can look into something like Babel (link in my comment) to help.